# Mongoose, validate $pull item from array in update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Given the following schema:

```
var BookSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  description: { type: String, required: false },
  authors: [AuthorSchema]
});

var AuthorSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
  type: { type: String, enum: ['FOO', 'BAR'], required: false }
}, {
  _id: false
});
```

I would like to validate that the authors array contains at least one object with type == 'FOO'.

This means that this should fail:

```
  var update = {
    $pull: {
      authors: {
        name: 'Mark'
      }
    }
  };

  Book.findByIdAndUpdate(book._id, update, {runValidators: true}, function(err, book) {
    ...
  });
```

if the document is currently:

```
{
  name: 'foo',
  authors: [{
    name: 'Mark',
    type: 'FOO'
  }]
}
```

I have tried to define a validator on the authors path:

```
BookSchema.path('authors').validate(function(authors) {
  return authors.filter(function(author) {
    return author.type === 'FOO';
  }).length > 0;
});
```

The problem is that the validation runs on the array in the update statement not the array that lives in the actual document.

I fully understand why, due to the fact that in an update the doc is not loaded into memory.

That being said, is it a 'right' way to do this kind of validate?  Maybe query for the doc first, then manually remove/add elements, then call save?